# Is there any difference between "closure" and "closing"

Tags: vocabulary

Is there any difference between the two in general usage? Can I use the two interchangeably in the context of talking about the end of a business?

For example,

> The closure took place at the end of last year.

Can I replace "***closure***" with "***closing***"?

Comment: Compare "The business is closing" with "the business is closure".

Comment: I'm aware that "closing" can be a verb. I mean when "closing" is used a noun. For example, "the closure took place at the end of last year." Can I replace "closure" with "closing"?

Comment: When you say, ...time for closing...., it means, closing that evening. If you say, ...time for closure... it may mean 'winding up'.  Closing is also used as participial, gerund/verbal nouns etc., whereas, 'closure' is the right noun form. What is the closing time? vs. What is the closure time? can distinguish the meanings.

Comment: Does it mean I have to say "the closure took place at the end of last year" but not "the closing took place at the end of last year"?

Answer (score 4):

Although in many cases the two can be exchanged freely, *closure* represents a greater level of finality and significance than *closing*.

The *closure* of a store or restaurant indicates an end to its existence as a business entity. *Closing* might mean the same, but is commonly used simply to mark the end of the daily business cycle.

*Closure* has the following several further meanings not represented by *closing*:

- The emotional state of satisfaction from certain adverse circumstances having ended and no longer causing stress or discomfort.
- Something that is able to be closed, though it is normally open. An example is a pocket with a zipper. This usage is less common.
- Various meanings  in mathematics and other technical fields.

Answer (score 0):

Among other definitions of ***closure***, [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/closure.html#C0-5) provides the following one:

> The collapse of a business. Ex: We have received a very apologetic letter about ***the closure of the West End Club***, but it really left us in the lurch.

Note, however, that "closure" can refer to a temporary state of being closed:

> The Mercer Gallery reopened at the weekend after a month-long closure
> for maintenance and improvements to the lighting system.

(example found on the same site of [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/closure.html))

As for ***closing***, you will find such definitions as:

> The final stage of an extended process or course of events

Or

> The act of something that stops

There is however one definition connected to the idea of bankruptcy:

> The condition or state of selling the assets of a business, especially due to bankruptcy

And [here](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/closing.html#C0-8) you can find synonyms as ***liquidation, shutting down***.

At the end of this little "investigation", I would thing that you can say either

> The closure/closing (I would add here *of the business*) took place at the end of last year.

but you will be surprised to find that [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20closure%20took%20place%2C%20the%20closing%20took%20place&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20closure%20took%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20closing%20took%20place%3B%2Cc0) gives definite preference to ***the closing took place***.

To avoid ambiguity though, I would simply say:

> The business was ***closed down*** at the end of last year.

[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk00WfUUu0mjnOOC_Z8g0gfULTe4emQ%3A1610202088262&source=hp&ei=6Lv5X7j1DP-JjLsP8JCqsAg&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAX_nJ-MGykIcsL5QtgQ-8PW5KLfyLRXo4&q=close%20down%20meaning&oq=close-down%20m&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgkIABDJAxAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46CQgjECcQRhD5AToECCMQJzoGCAAQChBDOgQIABBDOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoMCCMQyQMQJxBGEPkBOgUIABCxAzoLCC4QsQMQxwEQrwE6BwgAEBQQhwI6CAguELEDEIMBOgcIABCxAxBDOgUILhCxAzoCCC46BwgAEMkDEEM6BwguELEDEEM6CggAEMkDEBQQhwI6AggAOgUIABDJAzoECAAQCjoECAAQHjoHCAAQyQMQHlDNCli8J2DPNWgAcAB4AIABtgGIAdMJkgEDNi42mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab) defines the verb ***to close down*** as:

> - cease business or operation, especially permanently.
>
> *The company closed down some years later.*
>
> - cause a company or business to cease operation, ***especially permanently***.
>
> The government promised to close down the nuclear plants
> within twenty years"

Answer (score -1):

Closing is also a gerundive. I feel that closing should be used instead of closure,  as in the " closing of schools" instead of" the closure of schools "

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any difference between "closure" and "closing".

Yes, **closure** is a deverbal noun, **closing** is a gerund/participle/-ing form.

**Closure** indicates one complete instance of the action of the verb to close.

**Closing** indicates the action of the verb to close that was uncompleted, or still in progress, at the time referred to.

I hope this explanation will bring you closure.

*I hope this explanation will bring you closing.

Leave this door open! Closing will trap your fingers.

*Leave this door open! Closure will trap your fingers.

Answer (score -4):

Not necessarily. Closing is a verb that can be used in the present or future tense. Closure, on the other hand, is a noun that can technically be used in any tense.

Comment: Unfortunately, this information is misleading. *Closing* is a noun derived from the verb *to close*. A noun does not have tenses, so the claim that it can be *used in any tense* is either false or trivial depending on the interpretation.